# add multiple azure sql firewall rules in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have the following code that adds one firewall rule

```
resource "azurerm_sql_firewall_rule" "main" {
    name                        = "${azurerm_sql_server.main.name}-firewall"
    resource_group_name         = var.resource_group_name
    server_name                 = azurerm_sql_server.main.name
    start_ip_address            = "0.0.0.0"
    end_ip_address              = "0.0.0.0"
}
```

I have a number of rules I need to add, how would I do this in terraform and could the values come from a config file?

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If yes, please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, there are two ways to create a number of rules in the same code.

One is that use the `count` property in the resource. In this way, you can use the `count.index` to name the rules and use the list to store the `start_ip_address` and `end_ip_address` like below:

```
resource "azurerm_sql_firewall_rule" "main" {
    count                       = "${var.rule_number}"

    name                        = "${azurerm_sql_server.main.name}-firewall-${count.index}"
    resource_group_name         = var.resource_group_name
    server_name                 = azurerm_sql_server.main.name
    start_ip_address            = "${element(var.start_ip_address, count.index)}"
    end_ip_address              = "${element(var.end_ip_address, count.index)}"
}
```

This is the way that I recommend you, it's simple and suitable.

The other way is that use the for and for_each loop in your resource. Take a look at the [document](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each/) to learn about it. It's a little difficult, but I think it's not a problem for you.